# Why can't marking cycle phase reclaim non-empty old regions?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, g1gc

The article [G1: One Garbage Collector To Rule Them All](https://www.infoq.com/articles/G1-One-Garbage-Collector-To-Rule-Them-All) 
gives a detailed description of G1 GC.

However, one thing I feel really confused is that **why `G1 GC did not have any marking information` after we've just finished a marking cycle phase. Before we can do a mixed GC**, we still need to piggyback a young GC phase again for the mixed GC so as to collect non-empty old regions.

In the marking cycle, we have already done marking among the whole heap. In this case, we know what can be reclaimed in old regions. It makes me feel uncertain about the purpose of marking cycle phase.

I find that in slides: [Garbage Collector Details and Tuning - AWS](http://presentations2015.s3.amazonaws.com/40_presentation.pdf)(page **41**), `Cleanup phase → recycles empty old regions`. In marking cycle phase, we only collect old regions that are completely empty.
Why can we not reclaim not completely empty old regions? We even need to postpone collecting non-empty(not completely empty) old regions in a mixed GC phase. Since I think mixed GC phase is not necessary, we can do collection immediately after the marking cycle phase.

> Once G1 GC successfully completes the concurrent marking cycle, it has
>   the information that it needs to start the old generation collection.
>   Up until now, the collection of the old regions **was not possible** since
>   **G1 GC did not have any marking information** associated with those
>   regions. A collection that facilitates the compaction and evacuation
>   of old generation is appropriately called a 'mixed' collection since
>   G1 GC not only collects the eden and the survivor regions, but also
>   (optionally) adds old regions to the mix. Let us now discuss some
>   details that are important to understand a mixed collection.

I cannot understand why when we finish a `marking cycle phase`, we still don't know **any marking information** associated with those regions.

Does `those regions` mean those newly allocated objects in eden and survivor regions? Can we collect non-empty old regions during `CleanUp` phase in a marking phase?

Comment: Is it due to lost object problem described in slides page 35? In that case, we  cannot collect white object(live) as garbage so that we need mixed phase again to mark object C. (Context is in the ` Garbage Collector Details and Tuning`)

Comment: Where does that cite say that it doesn’t have the information? It clearly says “*Once G1 GC successfully completes the concurrent marking cycle, it **has** the information*…”. It continues with “*Up until now, … was not possible*” which means “*before that*…it was not possible”.